# Missing com.tridion.dynamiccontent.PageContentAssembler

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, broker

I have some WCF services that have been implemented against the Tridion 2013 SP1 Content Delivery / DD4T Provider.  When executing a query, I receive the following error:

```
<JavaException>
  <Type>java/lang/ClassNotFoundException</Type>
  <Message><![CDATA[com.tridion.dynamiccontent.PageContentAssembler]]></Message>
  <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.dynamiccontent.PageContentAssembler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
   at Amaze.TridionService.AmazeTridionPageService.GetContentByUrl(TridionPageRequest request) in f:\Development\Amaze.Tridion\Amaze.TridionService\Amaze.TridionPageService\TridionPageService.svc.cs:line 68
   at SyncInvokeGetContentByUrl(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)]]></StackTrace>
```

I've done the usual checks:

- Valid CD license
- No obvious errors in log files
- Ensured the JAR files are present and correct in the `/lib` folder

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `cd_dynamic.jar` is missing in the `lib` folder.

### Update:

Needs to remember that `cd_dynamic.jar` and `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` are dependent on each other.

Hence,

- `cd_dynamic.jar` should be placed in `lib` folder
- `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` should be placed in `config` folder

Comment: Thanks, this was the right answer!  Also it needed cd_dynamic_conf.xml in the /config folder.

Comment: @mpaton: You are right. Both Config (`cd_dynamic_conf.xml`) and Jar files are dependent on each other. I have updated the answer with more info.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this error in the past and it was simply because I was missing the cd_wai_conf.xml file from my config folder. The cd_wai.jar file was present, but could not be initialized because it couldn't read its configuration.

Copying a "default" cd_wai_conf.xml to the /bin/config folder, then restarting the app pool fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Tridion Content Delivery stack requires a HttpContext. It's used to start the JVM.

By default a WCF service doesn't have a HttpContext. You can however set a `web.config` setting to 'fix' this (not sure what the drawbacks are):

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: More nuanced: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-tridion-content-delivery-loads-configuration-files-in-dotnet